# How to connect a Bamboo remote agent from within Intranet

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

We have a Bamboo server running in the cloud and we would like to connect the machine that is in our local network. The problem is that this PC only has access to proxy that has only port 80 available and company would not allow to open any ports.

We want to avoid setting up new Bamboo instance in our local network.

Answer (score 1):

So I am assuming that

1) you have a PC on your LAN.  The PC can only talk to port 80 outgoing via a proxy

2) you have a bamboo server running a cloud service

3) you wish to initiate a connection from the bamboo server to the PC

Don't get your hopes up but this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161960/connect-with-ssh-through-a-proxy

explains how to use a http proxy to tunnel ssh.  Unfortunately most http proxies disallow the CONNECT method

Once you have the ssh to the remote cloud service set up then try it again 
with a -R option to allow a reverse tunnel

Then you should be able to connect via the reverse tunnel back to the Lan PC